# SIM Toolkit Permissions

Tags: mobile, sim-card, sim-toolkit

I'm doing a research on STK, the thing that is missing is do I need user's permissions to send and receive data to the operator?

What I know so far is that this tool is preinstalled in operating system, so isn't already have full permissions to send and receive in the background?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of SIM cards support STK and yes it can be used to send/receive information.

Permission for a SIM to send an SMS is normally device dependent, I remember the older Nokia phones had a setting that would prompt the user "allow SIM to send message". In my experience most newer devices (both Android and IOS) are setup such that the SIM can send SMSs in the background without user awareness.

Comment: Yes sending SMSs, but do I need user's permission each time I need to send SMS?

Comment: By most devices you mean Android and iOS?

Comment: This is not an answer. You can use comments to ask questions about the questioner question.